# form tag affecting css styling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm pretty terrible at css, and get by only on SO answers - however I can't find any explanation for this specific issue.

I have a form with one `textarea` and one `button`(`input/submit`), nothing else, I'm trying to have the `textarea` fill all of the screen except for the 30px taken up by the button at the very bottom of the screen so it looks something like this:

[image: horrific mspaint mockup i'm sorry]

I'm trying to achieve this using flex as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/3694461).

my body currently looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <form action="./save.php" method="post">
        <div class="row content">
            <textarea rows="1" cols="1" name="document" class="box1">text</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes." class="btn1">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my `btn1` and `box1` classes apply `width:100%; height:100%;` on both items, some basic color styling, padding and font changes, as well as a 1px border.

my remaining css looks like this

```
html,body { height:100%; margin:0; }
.box { display:flex; flex-flow:column; height:100%; width:100%; }
.row.header { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.row.content { flex: 1 1 auto; }
.row.footer { flex: 0 0 30px; }
```

it doesn't work, depending on the styling of `form` it either fills a small amount of the page, or both elements each take up a full page.

**however when I remove the `form` tag from my html entirely everything fixes itself and it displays and acts exactly as I would have expected.**

i've tried styling the `form` tag the same as `html,body`, also tried setting it to `hidden`, displaying as `block` and `inline-block` etc. however I can't seem to get it to not affect anything.

Is there a way I can make the `form` tag not affect styling at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form` tag has to be the flex container, not the `.box` DIV (`.box`' s only child is the `form` element, so that wouldn't make sense):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.row.footer {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}

.btn1,
.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn1 {
  background: red;
}

.box1 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <form action="./save.php" method="post">
    <div class="row content">
      <textarea rows="1" cols="1" name="document" class="box1">text</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer">
      <input type="submit" value="Save Changes." class="btn1">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much - knew it was something simple :)